# Trying to make an algorithm to organize direct payments for poker debt settling

Tags: algorithm

So I'm having a tough time figuring out how to model this problem. For a poker game I'm developing, players are represented with OOP, representing the amount of money the player put in to the table, and how much they cashed out with.

Since the money on the table cannot change, the winnings and losses will be equivalent. I want to minimize direct payments between winners and losers, so that the losers are given the smallest possible list of winners to pay, along with the amounts.

I could imagine this as a sort of graph/flow problem, or perhaps simply iterating down lists of winners and losers, sorted by the size of their debts/winnings.

Any other suggestions on how to model/solve this problem? Any help would be appreciated, and if there's any problem with the question, please tell me, happy to add any other necessary info/code.

Comment: Is this real money? If so, I don't know (there may be legal implications that are beyond my skills). If not, why don't you have the players with losses "pay the table", then the one with gain "retrieve their gains from the table" rather than bothering with peer-to-peer payments?

Comment: It's a friendly game which we settle among ourselves, which is legal in our state as "private/social games".

Comment: @Aaron We could do that, but it makes our games more complicated and is a burden on the dealer/table. It's just a personal project I'm working on so no legal issues.